# MAAS 2.4 - setting a node's default route

Tags: networking, maas

I've installed MAAS 2.4 and have commissioned a collection of nodes. On all nodes, PXE booting is performed on interface en0. en0 is configured via MAAS on a private, untagged, managed network. Interface en1 on all nodes are configured to attach to our corporate backbone.

After deploying, the default route for the deployed node(s) always points to the gateway IP of the PXE/MAAS network on interface en0. How do you set up MAAS to have a node's default route point to our corporate VLAN gateway via interface en1?

Answer (score 1):

There are two general solutions for this issue:

- Ensure your management network does not have a default gateway known to MAAS (this can be problematic, because MAAS controllers will report their network configuration to the region every ~30 seconds, and in doing so may repopulate the default gateway on the management VLAN, if it has been removed.)
- After commissioning your machine, use the [`set_default_gateway` API](https://docs.maas.io/2.4/en/api) to pick an interface to use as the default gateway.

As an aside, we're looking at a way to solve this in MAAS 2.6+ by using source-specific routing, so that only traffic sourced from the management interface will use its gateway. But this solution may not be able to support images less recent than Ubuntu 18.04 "bionic".